# How to merge polygons using GeoDataFrame?

Tags: geopandas

I would like to merge polygons (*parcels*) which are inside the white road (*which is a hole*) -- see the picture. 
The way I'm doing this is certainly a bad way because later, in my script, I have this error:
  `AttributeError: 'GeoSeries' object has no attribute '_geom'`

```
pa_fu = parcelles.unary_union
voirie = commune.difference(pa_fu) # commune is a big polygon which contains all the geometries

public = pd.DataFrame()
public['geometry'] = voirie
public['statut'] = ['public'] * public.size

prive = pd.DataFrame()
prive['geometry'] = pa_fu
prive['statut'] = ['prive'] * prive.size

decoupage = GeoDataFrame(pd.concat([public, prive]))
decoupage.crs=commune.crs # on fixe le système de projection identique à commune
cases_decoupage = overlay(cases, decoupage, how="intersection")
```

[image]

How can I merge these parcels and create a GeoDataFrame containing merged parcels and the white hole as a polygon?

Answer (score 3):

I found that

```
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True))
```

Seems to me that `pd.concat` strips something from `GeoSeries` and turns it into pandas `Series`, so we need to cast it back to `GeoSeries` (and `GeoDataFrame`).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem
as `df1` and `df2` has overlapping index, which `pd.concat` join the geometry into GeoSeries
using `ignore_index=True` does solve the problem